# Determining a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> 1. $$D_2 = \left\lbrace\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1} & 0 \\0 & a_{22}\end{bmatrix}: a_{1,1}, a_{2,2} \in \mathbb{R}\right\rbrace.$$
>      Determine a basis of $D_2$.
> 2. $$\mathbb{P}_2 = \lbrace a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 : a_0, a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$$
>      $$T : \mathbb{P}_2 \to \mathbb{P}_2 : T(\underline{f}) = \begin{pmatrix} \underline{f}(0) \\ \underline{f}(3) \end{pmatrix}.$$
>      Determine a basis for the kernel of $T$.

These were 2 questions from a midterm and I was wondering how I should get started?

Comment: In general, do you know what the usual basis for the space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices is? It consists of four matrices, and each matrix has a $1$ in some position and a $0$ in other positions. If you understand why that set is a basis, then the first exercise should not be difficult.

Comment: You could get started by actually typing your questions here instead of uploading an image... If you're not willing to make much effort, why should we?

Comment: Hi Eli. I've Latexed up your question. As zipirovich has mentioned, posting images is generally frowned upon here. You can edit your question to see what I've typed. Try playing around with it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Fill in the blanks:
   $$\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1} & 0 \\ 0 & a_{2,2} \end{bmatrix} = a_{1,1}\begin{bmatrix} \hspace{6pt} & \hspace{6pt} \\ \hspace{6pt} & \hspace{6pt} \end{bmatrix} + a_{2,2}\begin{bmatrix} \hspace{6pt} & \hspace{6pt} \\ \hspace{6pt} & \hspace{6pt} \end{bmatrix}.$$
   This should show that $D_2$ is spanned by two matrices. What else do you need to verify to show that these two matrices form a basis?
2. First, find the two equations in terms of $a_0, a_1, a_2$ that characterise when $\underline{f}(0) = 0$ and $\underline{f}(3) = 0$. Then find the solution to this system. If you parameterise this solution with a parameter $s$, then you should find you get a solution of the form:
   $$(a_0, a_1, a_2) = s(\hspace{30pt}).$$
   Then, this should easily lead to something of the form
   $$a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 = s(\hspace{45pt}).$$
   This should basically give you your basis.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, note that
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & 0 \\0 & a_{22}\end{bmatrix}=a_{11}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+a_{22}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

This means that you have found two matrices such that any matrix in the given set $D_2$ is a linear combination of them! So, they span your set. Can you show that they're linearly independent too?

For the second part, what do you know about a quadratic polynomial that vanishes at $t=0$ and $t=3$? Well,  $p_*(t)=(t-0)(t-3)$ is such a quadratic polynomial of course, but for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,  $\lambda p_*(t)$ works too. Can you show that these quadratic polynomials are all of the kernel of $T$?

Can you see why we're saying all this? Let us know if you needed more help.